# Power supply is flashing and clicking

Tags: power-supply, led, troubleshooting

I tried connecting the output of my 12V 5A power supply to a Peltier module (TEC1-12710) which has a maximum voltage of 12V and max current of 10 amperes. Following this, the power supply LED started flashing along with some clicking noise.

I connected the output to my multimeter and the voltage seemed to be increasing to 3V then back down to 0V and so on.

I think what is happening after some research online is that the power supply's overcurrent protection feature is triggering, maybe because the load is drawing too much current or something along those lines.

I connected the power supply to another Peltier module (TEC1-12706) I had which has a lower maximum current of ~6 amperes and it worked just fine.

So from all the testing I did I believe my theory might be correct that the overcurrent protection is triggering, but I'm not so sure how to move forward. Do I have to buy a completely brand new power supply, or is there a way of powering the TEC1-12710 with my current one?

[image]

Comment: It sounds like over-current protection is operating - not over-voltage. The power supply will attempt to supply 12 V at up to 5 A (note capitals). Once current exceeds 5 A the voltage will be reduced.

Comment: The overvoltage protection isn't triggering. The overcurrent protection is. Use a better power supply or a smaller Peltier. Yes you do need a 10A supply for that Peltier.

Comment: Yup sorry that's what I meant.  Can I still power it with 5A power supply, I really don't want to have to buy a new one?

Comment: only if you can find a way to limit the current it;s taking.

Comment: How would I go about doing that?

Comment: No you must supply more power even if using tandem operation if allowed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not overvoltage, but overcurrent.

You can't power a 10A load with a 5A supply.

Comment: The max current it's rated for is 10A, I don't have to power it with 10A do I?

Comment: No, but the peltier device will take all the current it needs at 12V, but the supply can't provide it. It says un the peltier datasheet that depending on the temperature, it typically needs 6-8 A, the 10A is just maximum it can be used with.

Comment: Would the best way to proceed just be buying a new power supply then? They're quite expensive though.

Comment: Or reduce the voltage externally. Or limit the current externally. Or adjust voltage down on power supply. Or get another peltier device.

Comment: Oh man, it's a 16-word answer, they are going to ban you.

Answer (score 0):

Overcurrent, you can't supply more than declared on the power supply to the load.